# Split every occurrence of Key=Value pairs in a string where the value include one or more spaces

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

I have a situation where user can enter commands with optional key value pairs  and value may contain spaces ..

here are 4 - different form  user input where key and value are separated with = sign and values have space:

```
"cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride"

"cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride server=prd"

"cmd=create-folder  name=cert - Test ride   server=dev site=Service"

"cmd=create-folder   name=cert - Test ride   server=dev site=Service permission=locked"
```

Requirement:
I am trying to parse this string and split into a dictionary based on the key and value present on a string .

If user enter First form of Statement, that wold produce a dictionary like :

```
query_dict = {

'cmd' : 'create-folder',
'name' : 'selfserve - Test ride'
}
```

if user enter second form of statement  that would produce /add the additional key /value pair

```
query_dict = {

'cmd' : 'create-folder',
'name' : 'selfserve - Test ride',
'server' : 'prd'

}
```

if user enter third form of statement  that would produce

```
query_dict ={

'cmd' : 'create-folder',
'name' : 'cert - Test ride',
'server' : 'dev',
'site': 'Service'
}
```

forth form produce the dictionary with key/value split like below

```
query_dict ={

'cmd' : 'create-folder',
 'name' : 'cert - Test ride',
'server' : 'dev',
 'site': 'Service',
 'permission' : 'locked' }
```

-idea is to parse a string where key and value are separated with = symbol and where the values can have one or more space and extract the matching key /value pair .

I tried multiple methods to match but unable to figure out a single generic regular expression pattern which can match/extract any string where we have this kind of pattern

Appreciate your help.

i tried several pattern map based different possible user input but that is not a scalable approach .
example :

i created three pattern to match three variety of user input but it would be nice if i can have one generic pattern that can match any combination of key=values in a string (i am hard coding the key in the pattern which is not ideal

```
'(cmd=create-folder).*(name=.*).*' ,
    '(cmd=create-pfolder).*(name=.*).*(server=.*).*',
    '(cmd=create-pfolder).*(name=.*).*(server=.*).*(site=.*)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `split`, and then `zip` to feed the `dict` constructor:

```
def get_dict(s):
    parts = re.split(r"\s*(\w+)=", s)
    return dict(zip(parts[1::2], parts[2::2]))
```

Example runs:

```
print(get_dict("cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride"))
print(get_dict("cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride server=prd"))
print(get_dict("cmd=create-folder  name=cert - Test ride   server=dev site=Service"))
print(get_dict("cmd=create-folder   name=cert - Test ride   server=dev site=Service permission=locked"))
```

Outputs:

```
{'cmd': 'create-folder', 'name': 'SelfServe - Test ride'}
{'cmd': 'create-folder', 'name': 'SelfServe - Test ride', 'server': 'prd'}
{'cmd': 'create-folder', 'name': 'cert - Test ride', 'server': 'dev', 'site': 'Service'}
{'cmd': 'create-folder', 'name': 'cert - Test ride', 'server': 'dev', 'site': 'Service', 'permission': 'locked'}
```

#### Explanation

Using this input as example:

```
"cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride"
```

The `split` regex identifies these parts:

```
"cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride"
 ^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^
```

The strings that are not matched by it will end up a results, so we have these:

```
 "", "create-folder", "SelfServe - Test ride"
```

The first string is empty, because it is what *precedes* the first match.

Now, as the regex has a capture group, the string that is captured by that group, is *also* returned in the result list, at *odd* indices. So `parts` ends up like this:

```
 ["", "cmd", "create-folder", "name", "SelfServe - Test ride"]
```

The keys we are interested in, occur at odd indices. We can get those with `parts[1::2]`, where `1` is the starting index, and `2` is the step.

The corresponding *values* for those keys occur at *even* indices, ignoring the empty string at index 0. So we get those with `parts[2::2]`. With the call to `zip`, we pair those keys and values together as we want them.

Finally, the `dict` constructor can take an argument with key/value pairs, which is exactly what that `zip` call provides.

Comment: Took a while for me to figure out the regex and split, it  but was worth of my time studying it.

Comment: Thanks, @Supertech, your comment motivated me to add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Much appreciated. It's very useful for people like me trying to improve their skills.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following regex:

```
(\S+)=([^=]+?)(?=\s\S+=|$)
```

**Regex Explanation**:

- `(\S+)`: first group holds any non-space character
- `=`: followed by a equal sign
- `([^=]+?)`: second group holds any non-equal character (least possible)
- `(?=\s\S+=|$)`: followed by either a space + word + `=`, or end of string character

Check the regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/rINtDb/1).

**Note**: Here the assumption is that your key (right-hand side of the pair) won't allow spaces.

---

You can then use this python code to retrieve your groups:

```
import re

strings = [
    "cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride",
    "cmd=create-folder    name=SelfServe - Test ride server=prd",
    "cmd=create-folder  name=cert - Test ride   server=dev site=Service",
    "cmd=create-folder   name=cert - Test ride   server=dev site=Service permission=locked"
]

pattern = r'(\S+)=([^=]+?)(?=\s\S+=|$)'

for string in strings:
    print(string)
    for match in re.findall(pattern, string):
        print(f'Group1: {match[0]} \t Group2: {match[1]}')
    print()
```

Check the python demo [here](https://www.online-python.com/DLeopKNkw7).

Comment: Hi @MattDMo , Thank you for your time and help. my values doesn't contain one or more spaces. I tried with the regex you provided and it always return the first key/value pair even when the value don't have space . Example : i tried below and always return the first key-pair  import re. 
chat_mesg_text="cmd=create-project name=Certified-TestApple server=test site=test"
print(user_query_kiv_str)
result = re.search('(\S+)=([^=]+?)(?=\s\w+=|$)',chat_mesg_text)
print(result)

Comment: Is there a way we can parse the value with all the word except the word that has = in it that way i can have any words in value except the key=

Comment: There's already a python demo, check it for more infos on how to use `re.findall` in place of `re.search`.

Comment: Hi @lemon !! that was best  and it worked !!! Thank you so much